# Not getting 3 frames/sec on Rebel Xs

Tags: canon, dslr

I have a Canon Rebel XS that I bought approx. 5 years ago. Just recently I noticed that I am not getting 3 frames per second anymore. (It was definitely getting 3 before.)

I shoot in the the large JPG format (not RAW) and I use a SanDisk Ultra SDHC 16GB memory card. (The speed does not increase if I shoot in small JPEG.)

I did some tests to see what I was actually getting. In manual, 1/500, f/5.6, auto focus off and continuous shooting mode; I'm shooting about 0.91 frames/second. Not cool.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/24342/9161

Comment: Not quite a duplicate since the other question doesn't mention FPS, just frames before the buffer fills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe maximum frame rates are just that - *maximum* frame rates. There are several things that will reduce the maximum frame rate.

- **High ISO** The higher the ISO you have selected, the slower the frame rate will be.
- **Noise Reduction** the stronger the in-camera noise reduction selected, the slower the frame rate will be.
- **AI Servo Mode** If you are using AI Servo AF mode the camera will refocus between each frame.
- **In low light** Most Canon User Manuals say "The continuous shooting speed might also
  decrease indoors and under low light"
- **Various other options** Other options that increase the amount of in-camera processing per shot can cause the frame rate to slow. Peripheral Illumination Correction, Auto Lighting Optimizer, Highlight Tone Priority, etc.
- **Low Battery Charge** When the charge state of the camera's battery is low it can reduce the frame rate.
- **Increased Detail** Increased amounts of fine detail in the scene, such as a field with grass.
- **Slow Shutter Speed** Selecting a very slow shutter speed will reduce the maximum frame rate. For example, if the shutter is staying open for 3/4 second per exposure, you won't get faster than about one frame per second.
- **Defective Memory Card** Although this usually manifests itself by reducing the number of shots before your buffer fills and increases the time it takes the buffer to clear and the frame rate while the buffer is full, it can also affect initial frame rate.

Since your question eliminates issues with AF and shutter speed, unless you are using a very high ISO or using strong noise reduction it sounds like there may be something mechanically wrong with your camera.

Comment: Thanks for the VERY thorough checklist! I'll be sure to remember this. :)